# Finding an object's position in an array in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var array1:Array = new Array();
var array2:Array = new Array();

var obj1:Object = new Object();

array1.push(obj1);
array2.push(obj1);
```

How can I do this
what command should I use?

```
//obj1's position in array1
//result: 0
//obj1's position in array2
//result: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the object position in the array stack,

You can use `indexOf`

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#indexOf()

For proof of concept

```
array1.push(obj1);

array1.push(obj2);

array1.push(obj3);

array1.push(obj4);

array1.push(obj5);

trace(array1.indexOf(obj5)); // Should return 4 [ 0 Ob1, 1, Obj2 ... etc]

trace(array1.indexOf(obj1)); // Should return 0
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a costly procedure if your array is very large. Consider using dictionary instead of an array if you need to do this kind of lookup a lot.